# Как создавать объекты налету?

Tags: python

Python. В программе требуется чтобы пользователь мог создавать столько объектов класса, сколько пожелает. Однако давать имена объектам (как и переменным, например) "налету" попросту невозможно. Как решить проблему?

Comment: покажите пожалуйста ваш пример, на основании которого вы сделали вывод что это `попросту невозможно`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно класть объекты в какую-то коллекцию, например массив, который будет доступен через свою переменную.

Comment: Вы наверно неправильно поняли, я хочу создавать объекты а не получать доступ к уже имеющимся.

Comment: вот создавайте и кладите в массив; или создавайте объекты, делайте из них (и можно тех, что были) массив, и кладите в переменную

Comment: `items = [Item(),Item()]`

Comment: `items = items + [Item()]`

Comment: как конкретно лучше делать (или не делать), зависит от среды, под которую бы пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Летаем, создаём:

```
for i in range(10):
  exec('a_' + str(i) + ' = 42')

print(a_0)
print(a_7)
```

Comment: a уж на Перле что творить можно ...

Answer (score 0):

Так то в питоне всё можно:

```
for i in range(3):
    globals()['i' + str(i)] = i

print(i0, i1, i2)

0 1 2
```

Но лучше и правда кладите объекты в коллекцию (список, словарь), можно даже внутри поля этого класса, чтобы класс "знал" все свои объекты и легко было посмотреть их список.

Answer (score 0):

Вы серьезно?

```
>>> class Foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> foo_lst = []
>>> def make_foo():
...     foo_lst.append(Foo())
...     
>>> make_foo()
>>> make_foo()
>>> make_foo()
>>> foo_lst
[<__main__.Foo object at 0x7fced407b690>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fced407bcd0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fced407b950>]
```